# Working with observer pattern

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I have an observer class below. my question is how could I set up up this class to listen(observe) to more than 1 subject?

```
    public class Observer2 implements Observer {
      private Subject robot;


      public Observer2(Subject robot){
       this.robot = robot;
       robot.registerObserver(this);
    }

      @Override
      public void update(){}
}
```

Comment: Pass 2 `Subject`s to the constructor, and register both.

Comment: Or in other words, if you know how to observe one, do the same for others.

Comment: If I pass 2 subjects that would mean I always would have to observe more than 1 subject? Do you mean public observer2(subject r, subject r){}?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a Subject class which stores all the observers in a list.

```
public abstract class Subject
{
    private ArrayList<Observer> observerList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void attach(Observer observer)
    {
        observerList.add(observer);
    }

    /**
     * Notifies observers to run execute
     */
    protected void notifyObservers()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < observerList.size(); i++)
        {
            observerList.get(i).update();
        }
    }
}
```

The typical Observer interface:

```
interface Observer
{
    void update();
}
```

Thereafter, you can trigger the observers using the `notifyObservers()` method.

Comment: I have this I just did not put it here. I just would like to know how to make one of my observers observe more than one subject

Answer (score 0):

Use a set.

```
public class MultiObserver extends Observer {
    private final Set<Subject> observed = new HashSet<>();

    public void observe(Subject s) {
        if (observed.add(s))
            s.registerObserver(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Java's [`Observer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) and [`Observable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html), which are set up for proper handling of multiple subjects:

```
class Robot extends Observable {
    public void act() {
        notifyObservers("Run!");
    }
}
class Cyborg extends Observable {
    public void act() {
        notifyObservers("Hide!");
    }
}

public class MyObserver implements Observer {
    @Override
    public void update(Observable subj, Object arg) {
        if (subj instanceof Robot) {
            System.out.println("Scary robot says " + arg);
        } else if (subj instanceof Cyborg) {
            System.out.println("Lovely cyborg says " + arg);
        } else {
            System.out.println("What's this? " + arg);
        }
    }
}
```

Registration is done differently:

```
// Construct observables
Robot r = new Robot();
Cyborg c = new Cyborg();
// Add observer to both of them
MyObserver o = new MyObserver();
r.addObserver(o);
c.addObserver(o);
r.act();
c.act();
```

Comment: For this I would have to have two observable classes? I just want a observer to be able to observe another subject should I add one down in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A ConcreteObserver can observe more than one Subject simply calling many times the **attach** method that the **Subject**s provide.
If the question is instead:

### *"How can a ConcreteObserver observe many ConcreteSubjects of different kind that have different types of state?"*

The answer is that in the **ConcreteObserver** the **update** method must be overloaded to manage many times equal to the types of states that the ConcreteObserver has to observe.
The ConcreteObserver must have also an array of states to store the observed states of the Subjects, with some mechanism to avoid that state of the same type coming from different Subject influence the state of each other.